# How to Raise/Handle Custom Signals in C?

Tags: c, signals, signal-handling

I am trying raise and handle custom signals in C. Unfortunately, I am having only partial success.

I am trying to follow this example: https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/signal_h/raise.php

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

sig_atomic_t signaled = 0;

#define TEST_SIGNAL_50 50
#define TEST_SIGNAL_51 51
#define TEST_SIGNAL_52 52
#define SIGUSR1 50

void sigHandler(int sig)
{
    signaled = 1;

    //Switch statement to handle all signals
    switch(sig) {
        case TEST_SIGNAL_50:
            printf("Case 50 is Matched.\n");
            break;
        case TEST_SIGNAL_51:
            printf("Case 51 is Matched.\n");
            break;
        case TEST_SIGNAL_52:
            printf("Case 52 is Matched.\n");
            break;
        case SIGINT:
            printf("SIGINT Case is Matched.\n");
            break;
        default:    //Raised signal is not a match
            printf("Raised signal %d is not a match.\n", sig);
            break;

    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World! Test\n");
    
    int raiseResult;
    void (*prev_handler)(int);

    //Register the signal handler
    //prev_handler = signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);     //This works
    //prev_handler = signal(TEST_SIGNAL_50, sigHandler);
    prev_handler = signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler);

    /* ... */
    //raiseResult = raise(SIGINT);                  //This works
    raiseResult = raise(SIGUSR1);
    /* ... */

    printf("raiseResult =%d.\n",raiseResult );
  
    printf("signaled =%d.\n",signaled);
  
    return 0;
}
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to handle the different signals by doing various actions. But for the moment, simply hitting the switch statement and getting the corresponding message would be a win.

I know that `SIGINT` is an actual signal. Thus, `sigHandler()` will work when I raise `SIGINT`. But otherwise, I am out of luck. The return value I get from `signal()` is negative; which tells me my failure has to do with `signal()`.

Does anyone understand what I am doing incorrectly with `signal()`?

Comment: Why are you redefining `SIGUSR1`?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @dbush Visual Studio Code considers SIGUSR1 as undefined and thus an error otherwise.

Comment: @ikegami currently Windows. There is a possibility for Linux later on.

Comment: Windows' support for signals is so poor it's not worth it. Same with standard C's signal facilities.

Comment: POSIX lets you use what's known as "real time signals" for application defined purposes if the standard ones aren't appropriate. But signal handling there is, while much more powerful and capable than Windows, fraught with peril - lots of rules and restrictions about what you can do in signal handlers - and potential for race conditions etc. causing issues if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: None of the three environments (Standard C, Windows, POSIX) let you try to assign arbitrary numbers as signal numbers. You have to use what's defined by system headers.

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals. That would be the issue! (Windows has Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break which are a tiny bit signal-like, so the C library might pretend they're signals, but that's it.)

Comment: signal.h is to be regarded as dirty old legacy stuff. It only ever (barely) worked on Unix and it is a poor system even there. I would advise to stay clear of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some users were indicating, Windows and the C compiler on Windows that I was using were not handling signals as cleanly as on a Linux system. Taking my code over to a Linux based system (in my case Ubuntu) and it would perform as expected.